# Relationship between chi-squared and standard normal distributions.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

It is well known that if $Z \sim N(0,1)$ then $Z^{2} \sim \chi^{2}(1)$. However, if we know that $X^{2} \sim \chi^{2}(1)$, under what conditions is it true that $X \sim N(0,1)$? As far as I know, this isn't an if and only if. I'm thinking it might be the case provided $X$ is a symmetric distribution.

Comment: A trivial counterexample would be to see that if $X = |Z|$ where $Z \sim \mathrm{Normal}(0,1)$, then $X^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$.  I also suspect that symmetry is a sufficient condition for uniqueness, but I don't have a proof.